# What is the alternative of using Qualifier annotation in XML in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

In Spring , if there are two bean ids which refer to the same class and we just want to inject values from only one bean, then we normally use the following annotations in conjunction :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("bean1")
```

How to achieve the same thing using the xml specification ? What is the alternative of using qualifier annotation in xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact alternative but you can use `autowire-candidate="false"` to all those beans which you want to exclude from being autowired apart from the one which is to be autowired. 
 Also you need to specify that particular bean which is eligible for autowiring by explicitly marking `primary="true"` for it and `primary="false"` for rest of them.
So roughly your xml configuration should look like below when you expect `bean1` to be autowired
`<bean id="bean1" class="x.y.z.ClassA" primary="true" autowire-candidate="true"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="x.y.z.ClassA" primary="false" autowire-candidate="false"/>
<bean id="bean3" class="x.y.z.ClassA" primary="false" autowire-candidate="false"/>`
Do note that both `autowire-candidate` and `primary` are properties for `beans` tag and has default value as `true`.