# What is the alternative of using @Qualifier annotation in XML in Spring?

Tags: spring

I have three classes Class A, Class B & Class C in my spring project.
Both Class A & Class B have reference of Class C & i want these references to refer 2 different objects of Class C.

Now i want to use auto-wiring byName. If i use java based configuration, then it can be achieved easily using @Autowired & @Qualifier annotations. But i want to achieve this using XML based configuration.

In below code, i want to link beanC_A with beanA & beanC_B with beanB using auto-wiring byName

```
   <!-- Definition for beans -->
   <bean id = "beanA" class = "com.test.A" autowire="byName"/>

   <bean id = "beanB" class = "com.test.B" autowire="byName"/>

   <bean id = "beanC_A" class = "com.test.C"/>

   <bean id = "beanC_B" class = "com.test.C"/>
```

I have already gone through [What is the alternative of using Qualifier annotation in XML in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058447/what-is-the-alternative-of-using-qualifier-annotation-in-xml-in-spring#)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the XML-based version of `@Qualifier` :

Short example:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="com.test.A1">
    <qualifier value = "AImpl1" />
</bean>
```

Please see the official documentation for more details: [XML-Configuration Qualifier in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the annotation like below:

```
@Qualifier("QualifiedForA")
private A a;
```

Below is the XML configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean id = "beanA" class = "com.test.A"/>
    <qualifier value = "QualifiedForA" />
</bean>
```